# JQuery: How to Change text color of multiselect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have a multi-select for month list drop down menu which will choose multiple options.I used JQuery Multiselect.js and this is the code: Notice: CDN Links Don't work here.But i've lib file that works fine.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Multi-select Dropdown List with Checkbox by CodexWorld</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.multiselect/1.13/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
body { font-family:'Open Sans' Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
ul,li { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
.label { color:#000; font-size:16px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
<h2>jQuery MultiSelect Basic Uses</h2>
<select name="langOpt[]" multiple id="langOpt" >
 <option value="All">All</option>
 <option value="Jan">January</option>
 <option value="Feb">February</option>
 <option value="Mar">March</option>
 <option value="Apr">April</option>
 <option value="May">May</option>
 <option value="Jun">June</option>
 <option value="Jul">July</option>
 <option value="Aug">August</option>
 <option value="Sep">September</option>
 <option value="Oct">October</option>
 <option value="Nov">November</option>
 <option value="Dec">December</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.multiselect/1.13/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
<script>
$('#langOpt').multiselect({ 
    placeholder: 'Select Months'
});

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Code works Fine.Right now the multi select has the following default text color which very fade.

[image]

But I want to change the text color to black.How can i do it please help.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the color of a placeholder.

See here [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.ui-multiselect {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Try adding !important to the end of color line. Or .ui-multiselect.ui-state-default as the selector.

Comment: thanks @janar2005, i just try what you suggest, but its not working `.ui-multiselect {
    color: #000  !important;
}`